# Is there a way to ensure __prepare__ and __new__ are called in a single line

Tags: python-3.x, metaprogramming

I have the following class that will be used as metaclass:

```
>>> class Meta(type):
...     @classmethod
...     def __prepare__(cls, name, bases):
...         return {'yes': 'it is'}
...     def __new__(cls, name, bases, ns):
...         return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, ns)
...
```

I would like to achieve the following with something like a `type(mcls, name, bases, ns)` statement that will call the `__prepare__` statement

```
>>> class Base(metaclass=Meta):
...     no = "it isn't"
... 
>>> type(Base), Base.no, Base.yes
(<class '__main__.Meta'>, "it isn't", 'it is')
```

Here is how I can achieve the same thing without a class statement but it's not pretty:

```
>>> ns = Meta.__prepare__('Base',)               #one line to prep the namespace
>>> ns.update({"no": "it isn't"})                #one line to update the namespace
>>> NewBase = type.__new__(Meta, 'Base', (), ns) #finally, call type.__new__
>>> type(NewBase), NewBase.no, NewBase.yes
(<class '__main__.Meta'>, "it isn't", 'it is')
```

I thought something like this might work:

```
>>> NewBase = type('Base', (), {'no':"it isn't"}, metaclass=Meta)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Base.__init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments
>>>
```

Nope.